# CSS e JScript - Redimensionar imagem onClick

Tags: javascript, css

Boa tarde !! 
Estou tentando executar o seguinte código porém não tenho conhecimento de como redimensionar a imagem para o tamanho do div, logo ele corta a imagem e pega somente o centro :( 
Podem me ajudar??

```js
function clickImagem(src)
{
  $('#conteudo').empty();
  var el = document.getElementById('conteudo');
  $(el).css('background',"url('"+src+"') no-repeat center ");
}
```

```css
  #conteudo{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#f1f;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="conteudo" class="conteudo"> </div>
<img src="https://tudocommoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/colar-de-namorados-cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-1.jpg" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
```

Comment: Veja se isso resolve:
$(el).css('background-image',"url('"+src+"')", 'background-size', '200px');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione o parâmetro `cover` em `background-size`

```js
function clickImagem(src)
{
  $('#conteudo').empty();
  var el = document.getElementById('conteudo');
  $(el).css('background',"url('"+src+"') no-repeat center");
  $(el).css('background-size',"cover");
}
```

```css
  #conteudo{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#f1f;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="conteudo" class="conteudo"> </div>
<img src="https://tudocommoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/colar-de-namorados-cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-1.jpg" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function clickImagem(src)
{
  $('#conteudo').empty();
  var el = document.getElementById('conteudo');
  $(el).html('<img src="'+src+'">')
}
```

```css
 #conteudo{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#f1f;
  }


img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="conteudo" class="conteudo"> </div>
<img src="https://tudocommoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/colar-de-namorados-cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-1.jpg" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
</body>
</html>
```